# Spring Boot heap usage in inactive state

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jvm

I have deployed a very simple spring boot application locally. It has only one class - controller. That's pretty much it.
What I've noticed is that heap allocation is not stable and is having peaks and sudden drops. Why is that happening. I have not done a single call to the app.

A view from VisualVM:
[image]

Comment: what makes you suspect this 'one class' app?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you are monitoring the application with VisualVM already leads to allocations in Java Heap.

VisualVM talks to JVM through JMX; you are basically observing the effect of this communication.

Answer (score 0):

Even tho no requests are being made the server application still does some kind of background stuff - then Garbage Collection happens. Here's a great article that explains it in-depth.

https://spring.io/blog/2015/12/10/spring-boot-memory-performance